# Bootstrap Scrollspy with large list

Tags: scrollspy

I have a large list of navbar items and scrollspy is working properly. I just want that when I scroll down and selected navbar items will be moved to the view area instead of I will scroll the navbar and see the selected navbar item. [my work screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYRfF.png)

I just search goolge and youtube but not find solution